# The dollar menu at your favorite tax-free fast food restaurant has 10 items. You have $15 to spend.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

Full Question:

> The dollar menu at your favorite tax-free fast food restaurant has 10 items. You have $15 to spend. How many different meals can you buy if you spend all your money and:
> a. Purchase at least one of each item.
> b. Possibly skip some items.
> c. Don’t get more than 2 of any particular item.

I've determined that a is:

> C(14,5)

and that b is:

> C(24,9)

I'm having trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong on part c. Here's what I'm trying.

> C(24,9) - [ C(12,1) C(21,11) - C(12,2) C(18,11) + C(12,3) C(15,11) - C(12,4) C(12,11) ]

My thinking is that we have the total meals to spend as C(24,9), and then since that is over-counting we subtract the meals for which we order 3 or more of an item.

Comment: (a) and (b) are both correct.  As for (c) your thought process you described is correct, however I do not see how the calculation matches.  Why $12$ in the top of the binomial coefficients?  It looks like you went and made a typographical error, thinking there were $12$ items on the menu for part (c).

Comment: What I was doing was taking my 15 to spend,and taking away 3 for the first item, so then I was picking from $12. Should that be changed to C(9,1) instead as I take one item away, and then choose from the next 9 items? @JMoravitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking over this, and with help from @JMoravitz, it does appear that I was thinking about 12 items instead of 10 for some reason.

For future references, I was able to get the answer by doing this:

> C(24,9) - [ C(10,1) C(21,9) - C(10,2) C(18,9) + C(10,3) C(15,9) - C(10,4) C(12,9) + C(10,5) C(9,9)]